# Displaying prominent pages of my website in Google Search Result

Tags: seo, google-search, google-search-console

I was wondering how I could display the prominent pages (such as About, Contact Us, Pricing, etc) of my website when it is searched for in Google. Currently Google search result only shows the homepage of my website. I want it to display prominent pages underneath as well, something like this:

[image]

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are called Google Sitelinks. You can find Google's explanation here. https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/47334?hl=en

The process is automated, you cannot add sitelinks, but you can remove ones you think shouldn't be there when you see them, through Google Webmaster Tools.